# JS prototype, create object with new features

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I just started with JS and I created a Contructor for a box. Now I want a box that can store Images and a box that can store text. How do I declare the new box objects, with prototype?

//box constructor

```
function Box(x, y, w, h) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w= w;
  this.h= h;    
}
```

//image box features:

```
 this.src = ....
 this.title = ...
```

//text box features:

```
  this.font = ...
  this.font-size=...
  this.color=....
```

Comment: Box.prototype.src = ""; and etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function Box(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;    
}
```

---

```
function ImageBox(x, y, w, h) {
    Box.call(this, x, y, w, h); // Apply Box function logic to new ImageBox object

    this.src = ....
    this.title = ...
}
// Make all ImageBox object inherit from an instance of Box
ImageBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype);
```

---

```
function TextBox(x, y, w, h) {
    Box.call(this, x, y, w, h); // Apply Box function logic to new TextBox object

    this.font = ...
    this.font-size =...
    this.color =....
}
// Make all TextBox object inherit from an instance of Box
TextBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype);
```

Comment: Thank You, that was a fast answer @amNotIam, I check it out!

Comment: @vuvu: You're welcome. And I just changed it to use `.call` instead of `.apply` so that you pass individual arguments. I have a feeling that your `TextBox` and `ImageBox` constructors will be passed more args that don't need to be sent on.

Comment: How do I define a TextBox then, with 7 parameters or how would the syntax look like for a new TextBox? (Sorry, I'm new)

Comment: @vuvu: Just add additional parameters to the function after the existing ones. And then to make a new `TextBox`, just call the function with `new` before the call. `var tb = new TextBox(0, 0, 100, 100, "foo-font", "12px", "maroon")`

Comment: @amnotiam You can use apply and pass the arguments keyword (that is an array of the params received). this way is more flexible

Comment: @fernandosavio: I originally had `.apply(this, arguments)`, but since OP is likely passing additional args to `TextBox` and `ImageBox` that aren't needed by `Box`, I thought it would be a little clearer and potentially safer to pass individual args.